# How can i mock HttpPostedFileBase mock

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mocking

How can I mock HttpPostedFileBase ?

its props are readonly and i need to test a fileupload module.

What mocking framework should i use?

```
    public class FileUpload
    {

        private readonly HttpPostedFileBase _file;
        private readonly string _filePath;

        public FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file, string path)
        {
            _file = file;
            _filePath = path;
        }
.......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpPostedFileBase` is an abstract class.  In your test, just create a new class inheriting from it and create your own stub version (hardcoding the method results you need to test).  What style of testing are you doing?

- mocking (testing for interaction)
- stubbing (testing with known values)
- fakes (using simpler objects to accomplish the task, not necessarily production code).

I think here stubbing would be most appropriate.

Alternatively, you could use Moq (or another framework) to help with this.